# OIDC - Confirming the approach for Authorise using Prompt None

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am currently going through some documentation on OIDC and one thing that I would like confirmation on is the /authorise flow using prompt=none

If I look at the Auth0 example below, it can't see any reference to a users access or ID Token being passed, which seems odd as the OP would surely need to know this to determine if any sessions are active.

> It could be passed on the Auth Header, or as a cookie but it isn't
>   mentioned or clear and Im hoping someone smarter than me can clarify
>   this.

Auth0 Example:

```
GET https://YOUR_DOMAIN/authorize
    ?response_type=id_token token&
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=...&
    state=...&
    scope=openid...&
    nonce=...&
    audience=...&
    response_mode=...&
    prompt=none
```

Comment: I think it'd be client_id where it recognises the user session is available with nonce. Also you can pass `id_token_hint=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJra...7r8soMCk8A7QdQpg` parameter in the request to ensure you're validating against right session.

Comment: is id_token_hint an official param? I haven't come across it before.

Answer (score 1):

In OIDC, a session cookie is stored in the browser once the user is successfully logged in at the IdP and that is the reason why you don't have to pass any user-related details. Once the user is logged-in, all the subsequent `/authorize` requests will find the cookie in the browser and will fetch the user details from it.

Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855992/1783165).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is odd that the use of cookies is not explicit or required, yet it seems to be an underlying requirement. This seems to be where OIDC has a grey area. If i research cookies in OIDC I see a huge range of options from two cookie solution to id token in cookie to various others. Which is right? Is there a right?

Answer (score 0):

To add some context to ManinGreen's answer:

- This flow typically only used for Single Page applications - by spinning up a hidden iframe to renew an access token without forcing an end user login
- The OIDC Client library does this - and manages the complexity involved
- Note that the single page app's own web domain is cookieless and you don't ever use cookies in your web UIs or APIs
- Other solutions (server side web apps, mobile apps etc) use refresh tokens instead

Some further info on my post:
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/